# Am I hashing the data in the file itself, or just the reference?

Tags: javascript, events, hash

I am attempting to create an app where I upload a file to a website and then I submit a hash of that file onto Ethereum. I am unsure whether I am hashing the actual file below or just the reference to the file.

Any suggestions for the script below?

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const hash = web3.sha3(e.target.value);

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly your want to upload a file from the client machine to the web application using the standard HTML tag `<input type="file">` and then hash the 
content of the file.

Your code is actually hashing the full path of the file.

If you want to read the content of a file, I recommend to use `FileReader` like this:

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
  <label for="input-file">Specify a file:</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="input-file">
</div>

<div>
  Content: <textarea id="content-target"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  Content Hash: <textarea id="hash-target"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
document.getElementById('input-file').addEventListener('change', event => {
    const input = event.target
    if ('files' in input && input.files.length > 0) {

        read(input.files[0]).then(content => {
            document.getElementById('content-target').value = content;
            document.getElementById('hash-target').value = web3.sha3(content, { encoding: 'hex' }); // << Specify you are hashing Base16 (hexadecimal)
        });

    }
})

function read(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onload = event => {
            // Convert Array Buffer to Base16
            var u = new Uint8Array(event.target.result),
            a = new Array(u.length),
            i = u.length;
            while (i--) // map to hex
                a[i] = (u[i] < 16 ? '0' : '') + u[i].toString(16);
            u = null; // free memory
            resolve(a.join("")); 
        }
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    });
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

You can also see and run the code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jsp9yqa/6/)

Comment: Thank you that was very thorough.

Comment: Question, when I hash an image using the code you provided above, the hash is different than when I hashed it using [this website](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256_checksum.html). Do you know why this is?

Comment: Hey,, I just updated the answer to work with binary files (image for example). Basically whatever the content uploaded to the browser, I convert it to Base 16 and specify `web3.sha3` that the content is Base 16

Comment: Try the the new JSFiddle

Comment: Thanks for the new code! One more question.  I created a text file with only the following text "hey nadir". when I hash web3.sha3("hey nadir") in my console, I get the following value:  0x52664ba0d7d4be6e1bd36db7b79bb2aff01c58013965771bcd238acdb02b368c  When I upload upload the text file into the app with your new code, I get the following value:  0x8efc689147bd83633b6603cc8462b4c26eaf4c88c841725b190b758320982a98 . Why is that?

Comment: That's because you must have an invisible blank character (like a new line) at the end or beginning of the file which changed completely the hash. You can for example use the following unix command to remove new line `\n`: `$ tr -d '\n' < myfile > newMyFile`

Comment: Hi Greg, why did you choose to map the file into a hexidecimal value before hashing? Thank you for all of your help so far.